# Populate mysql db to Shotgun server using Python

Tags: mysql, python

I've an internal mysql database. On each creation, modification or deletion of the content of this db, I need to run a python script to replicate those information into another software web server.

What's the more efficient way to achieve this?

- using triggers to run python? I think it's going to be too slow
- create some logs and live process them? like an event loop or something?

Comment: Are both servers owned/managed by the same person/company?  Consider replication.

Comment: [python-mysql-replication](https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication) can be used to read a replication stream. Why are you replicating to the web server rather than the webserver using your data? Or replicating to a non-internal web server on which the webserver uses data.